# Photoshop layer visibility reversed

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5, photoshop-cs5, layers

I have visible layers and hidden layers; I am looking for a way "shortcut" that will make the hide the visible layers and reveal the hidden ones. Anybody know how?

Comment: You might be able to create an "Action" that does what you want. Look up Actions in its Help.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop doesn't have a default  key for that, but if you go to the Keyboard Shortcuts configuration (Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts) under 'Layers' there is a 'Hide Layers' option where you can bind your own shortcut as you wish.